# cannot boot-up a compiled spring-native app using Hibernate Search

Tags: spring-native

I compiled a spring-boot webapp using Hibernate Search but it cannot start, the app is using entities from a PostgreSQL database like "users" to enable full text search on first/last names.

Here is the pom.xml file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-native-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-native-test</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Native Test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <repackage.classifier/>
        <spring-native.version>0.12.0</spring-native.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.0.9</vaadin.version>
    </properties>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.10.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${repackage.classifier}</classifier>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <properties>
                <repackage.classifier>exec</repackage.classifier>
                <native-buildtools.version>0.9.11</native-buildtools.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native-buildtools.version}</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Even if I am not using it, commenting all the annotations for indexation (like "@Field", "@Indexed", I get the following exception at boot-up.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-native-test:2.6.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-native-test:2.6.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-native-test:2.6.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-native-test:2.6.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-native-test:2.6.8]
        at com.example.RestServiceApplication.main(RestServiceApplication.java:24) ~[spring-native-test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586) ~[spring-native-test:na]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813) ~[na:na]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.collectServiceIfNotDuplicate(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:276) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:187) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:224) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:479) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:222) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-native-test:5.3.20]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[spring-native-test:na]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[spring-native-test:na]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:789) ~[na:na]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid logger interface org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.Log (implementation not found in jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1c53fd30)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2564) ~[spring-native-test:3.4.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530) ~[spring-native-test:3.4.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516) ~[spring-native-test:3.4.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:31) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:26) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.<clinit>(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:37) ~[spring-native-test:5.11.10.Final]
```

If I execute the JAR file, generated by the compilation process, the server starts successfully and the search returns expected results: `java -jar target/spring-native-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar`

Did anyone compile and was able to run a spring project that uses Hibernate Search?

Comment: I tried an event lighter project, it appears that the cause is a "conflict" between the Hibernate Search library and the JPA one. I added an issue on github [here is the link](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/1645)

Comment: If someone sees this issue... the spring-native project (link in my previous comment) concluded that they are not concerned...